# SQL query help to compare two ids present as a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column named link_name. It contains id of two assets like (123_456). I need to check if the voltage(have a column in main table) of asset 123 matches with voltage of asset 456.

I'm unable to find any solution for this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; a detailed description of what it means to match both voltages; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output for your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If your sample data looks like ...

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select '123' "ASSET", 110 "VOLTAGE", 'Some other column(s)' "COL_3" From Dual Union All
            Select '234' "ASSET", 220 "VOLTAGE", 'Some other column(s)' "COL_3" From Dual Union All
            Select '345' "ASSET", 360 "VOLTAGE", 'Some other column(s)' "COL_3" From Dual Union All
            Select '456' "ASSET", 110 "VOLTAGE", 'Some other column(s)' "COL_3" From Dual Union All
            Select '567' "ASSET", 220 "VOLTAGE", 'Some other column(s)' "COL_3" From Dual 
        ),
    assets AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", 'Name for ID 1' "A_NAME", '123_234' "LINK_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'Name for ID 2' "A_NAME", '345_456' "LINK_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", 'Name for ID 3' "A_NAME", '123_456' "LINK_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "ID", 'Name for ID 4' "A_NAME", '234_567' "LINK_NAME" From Dual 
        )
```

You can use SUBSTR() function to join two assets from yout table using two JOIN  ON conditions.

```sql
Select
    a.LINK_NAME, 
    SubStr(a.LINK_NAME, 1, InStr(a.LINK_NAME, '_') - 1) "ASSET_1",  
    SubStr(a.LINK_NAME, InStr(a.LINK_NAME, '_') + 1) "ASSET_2",
    t1.VOLTAGE "VOLTAGE_1",
    t2.VOLTAGE "VOLTAGE_2",
    CASE WHEN t1.VOLTAGE = t2.VOLTAGE THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END "MATCH"
From
    assets a
Inner Join
    tbl t1 ON(t1.ASSET = SubStr(a.LINK_NAME, 1, InStr(a.LINK_NAME, '_') - 1))
Inner Join
    tbl t2 ON(t2.ASSET = SubStr(a.LINK_NAME, InStr(a.LINK_NAME, '_') + 1))
Order By
  a.LINK_NAME
```

R e s u l t :

| LINK_NAME | ASSET_1 | ASSET_2 | VOLTAGE_1 | VOLTAGE_2 | MATCH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123_234 | 123 | 234 | 110 | 220 | N |
| 123_456 | 123 | 456 | 110 | 110 | Y |
| 234_567 | 234 | 567 | 220 | 220 | Y |
| 345_456 | 345 | 456 | 360 | 110 | N |